# How to use Polymer to consume external restful api

Tags: ajax, api, rest, polymer

I am learning Polymer. I tried using core-ajax to consume catfacts api (http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=5 ), but turned out as CORS error. Some people suggest using core-shared-lib instead, but seems like core-shared-lib is for importing external libraries. Is there anyway I can use polymer to make GET request to some external api without running into CORS problem?

Comment: I didn't understand CORS well enough (still not). But I found a very good library called [aja.js](http://krampstudio.com/aja.js/) on bower. I used that to make JSONP request to an external api in my polymer app and it works. I still haven't figured out how to use polymer to do this though. But thank you Andrew for replying me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This evening I read through the entire 0.9 (beta) documentation. Happened to come across what you're talking about. I'm just learning as well.

CORS stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. In order for your Polymer app to load an external resource, you need to make sure you have CORS enabled on your server. It looks as though this is a security restriction imposed by browsers.

Link to Q&A on Polymer site: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/faq.html#externalfiles

How do I enable CORS? http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: But I'm just making a static site with no server. I would like to access some APIs provided by other servers. I do not have control over how the server is implemented.

Comment: Try this article: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/